# Regular Expression on Django doesn't work

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm relatively new to Django so I am doing [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_tutorial.pdf), but I encountered a problem with regular expressions:

For this view

```
def viewArticle(request, month, year):
     text = "Displaying articles of : %s/%s"%(year, month)
     return HttpResponse(text)
```

I am supposed to create a url like that

```
url(r'^articles/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', 'viewArticles', name='articles')
```

and it works perfectly, for example when I enter http://.../articles/12/2014 I get "Displaying articles of: 12 / 2014", as I should.

However, later (on page 27 of the PDF) I am advised to change the url to this:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P\d{2})/(?P\d{4})', 'viewArticles', name='articles'),
```

and now it doesn't work anymore. Why could that be and how can I change my code? Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: No, not `(?P\d{2})` but `(?P<name>\d{2})`.

Comment: Caveat: That tutorial is for a pretty old version of Django. I think the Django docs are very well written to act as a standard reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial says that you may use [*named capturing groups*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) here:

> `(?P<name>...)`
>   Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group is accessible via the symbolic group name *name*. Group names must be valid Python identifiers, and each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression. A symbolic group is also a numbered group, just as if the group were not named.

The correct declaration of a named capturing group is `(?P<name>...)`:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<year>\d{4})', 'viewArticles', name='articles')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it definitely works! I just don't see what is the advantage over url(r'^articles/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', '...

Comment: `(\d{2})` is a *numbered* capturing group. In this case, the captures are passed as positional arguments to a view. When named groups are used, they are passed as keyword arguments to a view. ["In practice, this means your URLconfs are slightly more explicit and less prone to argument-order bugs – and you can reorder the arguments in your views’ function definitions. Of course, these benefits come at the cost of brevity; some developers find the named-group syntax ugly and too verbose."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Comment: Thank you very much, Wiktor!